# Macro for excel 2010 to automate name manager

Tags: excel, vba

My requirement is to create a `macro` in `excel 2010` which will automatically assign or create names to equidistant cells using the `Name Manager` (Ribbon > Formula > Name Manager).

```
For e.g. Cell A1 to be named as Name_1, Cell A11 to be named as Name_2, Cell A21 to be named as Name_3 and so on.
```

Hope this makes sense else ask for clarification. Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Sorry @PeterAlbert I have not tried anything on the macro thing. I am trying to do it manually as I am not an expert in macro. That's why seeking your help :-)

Comment: Try the macro recorder - record a macro where you create two names. Then look at the code and try to modify it. Show us some effort and we're happy to support you!

Comment: Sounds good! I will certainly try this. Thanks @PeterAlbert!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter, your able guidance helped me to succeed (got help from Siddharth Rout as well!) :) Thanks! Please find below my code -

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Define the variables
Dim vRangeDefined, vRowCount, vRowIndex, vColIndex, vCounter, vCellValue As String, vNameValue As String

'Define the range where the values are entered
vRangeDefined = ActiveSheet.Range("A:B").Value
vRowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For vCounter = 2 To vRowCount
    vCellValue = vRangeDefined(vCounter, 1)
    vNameValue = vRangeDefined(vCounter, 2)
    'Divide the Cell Value in two parts
    vRowIndex = Left(vCellValue, 1)
    vColIndex = Right(vCellValue, Len(vCellValue) - 1)
    'MsgBox vRowIndex & "-" & vColIndex

   'Assign the names to cells as per the range
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
        Name:=vNameValue, _
        RefersTo:="='Sheet1'!$" & vRowIndex & "$" & vColIndex

Next

MsgBox "Process complete..."

End Sub
```